# PHP|SQL Natural Language mode vs. Two queries

Tags: php, mysql

I just wondering...

What is the difference between this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
WHERE MATCH (col1,col2,col3) 
AGAINST ('keyword' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
```

and this:

```
SELECT (...), MATCH ( description ) AGAINST ( '$searchname' ) AS relevance 
FROM places 
WHERE MATCH ( description ) AGAINST ( '$searchname' )
ORDER BY relevance DESC
```

Both give us results ordered by relevance right?